# Add more colums to the table and input values in dynamoDB JS shell

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I have created a table in dynamoDB JS shell with stu_id as the hash_key_attribute.

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'student_test',
    KeySchema: [ 
        { // Required HASH type attribute
            AttributeName: 'stu_id',
            KeyType: 'HASH',
        },
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [ 
        {
            AttributeName: 'stu_id',
            AttributeType: 'N',             },
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: { // required provisioned throughput for the table
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1, 
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1, 
    },
};
dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response

});
```

Now I want to add stu_name and school columns and insert the values. Tried defining the column names in GlobalSecondaryIndexes but it didn't work.

I am using DynamoDB local.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to update the table with **new GSI**.

In the below code, I have defined the GSI with name `student_test_name_gsi` and attributes `stu_name` as Hash key and `stu_id` as Range key

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'student_test',
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        {
            AttributeName: 'stu_id',
            AttributeType: 'N',             },
        {
            AttributeName: 'stu_name',
            AttributeType: 'S',             },
    ],
        GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdates: [
            {
              Create: {
                IndexName: 'student_test_name_gsi', /* required */
                KeySchema: [ /* required */
                  {
                    AttributeName: 'stu_name', /* required */
                    KeyType: 'HASH' /* required */
                  },
                  { // Optional RANGE key type for HASH + RANGE secondary indexes
                      AttributeName: 'stu_id',
                      KeyType: 'RANGE',
                  }
                  /* more items */
                ],
                Projection: { /* required */
                  ProjectionType: 'ALL'
                },
                ProvisionedThroughput: { /* required */
                  ReadCapacityUnits: 20, /* required */
                  WriteCapacityUnits: 20 /* required */
                }
              },
            },
            /* more items */
          ],
};

dynamodb.updateTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to update table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Updated table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes this works fine. But I cant view the created tables(with column names and data)? Can I do it with JS shell?

Comment: You can't view the GSI separately. However, you can use "describe" command (aws cli command) and see that GSI has been created. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/describe-table.html

Comment: can't I do using JS shell? Because I am not using AWS CLI

Comment: yes, you can. Please refer this https://gist.github.com/notionquest/8f4b52b217a52b59330093750c84d3b7